# is it possible to add label tag inside option?

Tags: drop-down-menu, html-select, dropdown

I'm trying to do something like this on the dropdown

[image]

I already tried different tag but failed to see the expected

```
<option id="makeDefault" value="0">Make <label class="option-placeholder">e.g. BMW, Mercedes</label></option>
```

Comment: did you mean to say if you can use placeholder inside option tag like text field?

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>MAKE e.g. BMW...</option>
        <option value="0">list item 1</option>
        <option value="1">list item 2</option>
    </select>
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/L0k6x0dh/1/

Comment: it okay but im having issue with the design inside the option. As you can notice, the word "Make" is different from other words.